# Get all posts with empty meta_value

Tags: wp-query, loop

I am using this query for my loop and it is working except when `meta_value` is empty. In this case it returns empty result. Instead I want to get all results when `meta_value` is empty.

Here is my code

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'state',
            'value'   => 'Alabama',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'country',
            'value'   => $region,
        ),
    ),
) );
```

I want to get all results in state Alabama when variable region will be empty. Any suggestion about this will be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess, you need `meta_compare`, have a look at examples in this [Developer resource](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to query for region field only if `$region` variable is not empty? If so, this should work and it will be much prettier code than the one you suggested:

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'state',
        'value'   => 'Alabama',
    ),
);

if ( $region ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'country',
        'value'   => $region,
    );
}

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and yes it is much prettier code and best way to achieve this. But i was able to get desired results with above mention code in my own answer last night.

Comment: Your answer will get a little bit different results. Your code will ignore posts without `country` meta_value at all. My code will still return such posts.

Comment: Okay i will test my posts again and then in this case will implement your code. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
             'key'     => 'state',
             'value'   => 'Alabama',
        ),
        array(
             'key'     => 'country',
             'value'   => $region,
             'compare' => $region ? "=" : "!=",
        ),
     ),
   ));
```